# How to show tabs and action bar in the same activity of android application?

Tags: android, android-studio

i am developing android application. i extend my class to Tab Activity.
while i am using getActionBar() or getSupportActionBar(), the activity stops working. when i extend my activity to Activity or ActionBarActivity getTabHost() will not work. Any one pls help me. thanks in advance.

```
Here is my coding.

public class CommonTabActivity extends TabActivity
        implements OnTabChangeListener {

    TabHost tabHost;
    Bundle response = new Bundle();
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_tab);

        ....

        tabHost = getTabHost();

        ....

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extend your activity to AppCompatActivity (ActionbarActivity is deprecated now), use tablayout from android design library to show tabs and associate viewpager to tablayout to switch between fragments corresponding to each tab. 
your activity layout would be something like this.

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

There are plenty of examples available to implement this.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: thank u. but import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout is not supported. it showing error.

Comment: Ramya, you need to add     compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
in your gradle file to access these views.

Comment: pls tell me where i can found  com.android.support:design:22.2.0

Comment: you need not do anything except adding  this line inside dependencies 

    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'